# NetSuite: access sales order field from packing slip advance template

Tags: netsuite

This is my first time to post a question and I need some help. I working with Packing slip advance template. Now I want access some fields and items sublist in sales order form but I can't. Can some one help me?
This is my code to access list items and access to get fields from sales order form. 
[My code from advance PDF/HTML templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojde2.png)

```
<#list salesorder.item as item>
<tr>
    <td>${item?counter}</td>
    <td>${item.itemid}</td>
    <td>${item.description}</td>
    <td>${item.quantity}</td>
    <td>${item.units}</td>
    <td>${item.rate}</td>
    <td>${item.amount}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Tax Code Summary <br/></td>
    <td>Tax rate <br/> </td>
    <td>Total Net <br/> ${salesorder.subtotal} </td>
    <td>Total Tax <br/> ${salesorder.taxtotal}</td>
    <td><b>${salesorder.total}</b></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please include your code directly instead of using a picture.

Comment: Can I include my code from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your items list and it appeared to be working as expected for me. The default list is very similar to yours and works the same:

```
<#list salesorder.item as tranline>
<tr>
    <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${tranline.item}</span><br />${tranline.description}</td>
    <td colspan="3">${tranline.options}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantityordered}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantityremaining}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantity}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
```

One thing to note is that `${item.itemid}` won't work. You can do a double join, however, to get the id like this: `${item.item.internalid}`.

As for the extra sales order fields, unfortunately, not all those fields can be accessed. Specifically, the ones in the total box are not accessible from the packing slip advanced pdf. You could, however, try to capture those total fields in a custom body field on the sales order using a workflow, and then display the custom field in your advanced pdf printout.

Comment: The list still not work for me. I don't know why. But you right about the fields in total box. I think I need to do what you say to access that field. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the list fields could you try uploading your whole file to pastebin or something similar and post a link? There might be something above that's conflicting with the list code because what you've written definitely should work.

Comment: About the list fields, I think I need to add sales order record in Suitelet script to access this. But now my new problem is I can't add the right internal ID of this sales order in my Suitelet script. If I add the specify ID then it's true but the dynamic ID for each form then I don't know how. Can you help me? I've search about this in Suitelet but I can't find the right thing.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with how you're adding your record to the render object in your Suitelet. You'll have to show me your Suitelet code so I can take a look. I might recommend creating another question here on stack overflow.